# Why exponent of exponent multiplied?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have an expression like ${2^2}^3$, then why are the powers multiplied? In other words, why is the above expression equal to $2^6$ not $2^8$?

Comment: The expression you wrote doesn't compile in LaTeX. Do you mean `2^2^3` or $2^{2^3}$ or $(2^2)^3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Rolf Hoyer writes, *exponentiation is not associative*, hence ${2^2}^3$ would result in an ambiguity: for this reason, when we write $2^{2^3}$ it is always meant to be
$$2^{(2^3)}=2^8.$$
Otherwise, if we mean
$$(2^2)^3=2^{2\cdot 3}=2^6$$
brackets must appear.

In general,
$$x^{a^{b^{c^{\cdots}}}} =
x^{{\left(a^{\left(b^{\left({c^{(\cdots)}}\right)}\right)}\right)}}\ne
(((x^a)^b)^c)^{\cdots}=x^{a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot \ldots}$$
while, for example,
$$
{{\left(x^{(a^b)}\right)}^c}^{\ldots}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x^{{\left({(a^b)}^c\right)}^{\ldots}}$$
must be explicitly denoted with brakets.

This, by the way, is one of the things making it difficult to correctly type your examination text by sms... ;)

Comment: I disagree. Exponentiation is usually considered to be *right associative*! See [Wikipedia on exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties).

Comment: @Christoph: uff! fixed all brackets! Leave your comment as a reference, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Exponentiation is not associative, there is a real difference between $(2^2)^3$ and $2^{(2^3)}$.